# How to check `data-method` in rspec link matcher

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I have a RSpec test which aims to ensure that a link is present on a web page.

Here is what the link looks like:

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="put" href="/change-user">Change user</a>
```

Here is my test:

```rb
subject { page }
visit user_path(user)

it { should have_link('Change user', href: change_user_path(user)) }
```

I would like to add a condition to this test ensuring that the link has the value "put" as `data-method` attribute.

How could I add this check to my test?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that it was possible to pass a block to the `have_link` matcher. This block will be called with the element found by capybara.

Inside this block it is then possible to verify some conditions in the link:

```rb
subject { page }
visit user_path(user)

it "shows the change user link" do
  expect(subject).to have_link(
      'Change user', 
      href: change_user_path(user)
    ) { |link| link["data-method"] == "put" }
end
```

Comment: The filter block is supposed to return a boolean - not another expectation so you probably want something like   `{ |link| link["data-method"] == "put" }` as your filter block

Comment: ho nice, thanks. It makes the test shorter. I'll update my response with this change.

Answer (score 1):

Capybara provides [different strategies](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/api/selectors) to locate elements.

The [`:element` selector](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/api/selectors.html#element) allows you to check on attributes:

```rb
user_link = find_link('Change user', href: change_user_path(user))
expect(user_link).to match_selector(:element, 'data-method' => 'put)
```

If you plan to do this often, you could extend the [`:link` selector](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/api/selectors.html#link) to support a `:method` filter.

```rb
Capybara::Selector[:link].instance_eval do
  expression_filter(:method) do |expression, value|
    builder(expression).add_attribute_conditions('data-method': value)
  end
  describe_expression_filters do |**options|
    if (method = options[:method])
      " with method #{method.inspect}"
    end
  end
end
```

and then use it as:

```rb
should have_link('Change user', href: change_user_path(user), method: :put)
```